# Finding the equation of a wave from a given graph.

Tags: wave-equation

I am not exactly sure whether to ask it on physics SE or math SE, but I think it is suited here[image]

Clearly, the wave is moving in the positive x direction

Using the general wave equation
$$y=A\sin(\omega t + kx + \phi _0)$$

At $x=0$
$$\omega t + \phi_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
At $t=0$
$$kx+\phi_0=\frac{-\pi}{6}$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Is there anything like a scale on the time axis of your diagram?

Comment: @WW1 no scale. Ofc, with a scale it would have been much simpler

Comment: Isn't the whole graph a $y$ vs $t$ graph at $x = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as the wave velocity $=\frac{-w}{k}=v$ in the positive x Direction, let the wave equation be $y=A \sin(wt-kx+\phi)$, to avoid getting negative values later.

Given graph is for particle at $x=0$. So it's motion can be described as $y=A \sin(wt + \phi)$.
At $t=0, y=-\frac{A}{2}$. So $\sin(\phi)=-\frac{1}{2}$.
Notice that the velocity of the particle is "down"/away from equilibrium position, indicating that the value of $\phi$ is the first solution to the above equation. So $\phi = \frac{7π}{6}$.

To determine $w$ there *must* be some other information(missing), apart from the given equation, such as intercept make by graph with x axis for the first time etc.

With that information, we can substitute for $y=0$ and solve for $w$. And with this we can get value of k as well, using $\frac{w}{k}=v$ (only the magnitude here, as we have already determined their signs).

Comment: That's what I said in the comments.